# Is there a way to chainload e.g. Windows from within Linux

Tags: linux, windows

What I want to do is to start e.g. a Windows from a second partition of my harddisk from a running linux system without a reboot.
Basically the idea would be to load the boot sector of the Windows partition to memory and then start that.

The obvious question is why would I want that. My idea here is to have a small linux partition that my PC boots into on every reset and in this Linux partition I would run a simple server which I can control from the network. This server could then act on commands from the network like "restore a Windows image to a partition", "backup a partition" or "boot / switch to a partition".

One way this could be done is to implement such a server e.g. in Grub itself, but this sounds like quite an overkill since e.g. my backup routine might need a quite complex logic etc...

So the basic outline of such a program would look like this.

```
// read first three sectors of the Volume Boot Record
p = malloc(512*3);
fd = fopen("/dev/sda1", "rb");
fread(p, 512*3, 1, fd);

// And then jump to the first instruction to execute it
jmp(p);
```

If anyone has done something similar, I would appreciate a tip on how to do this!

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. (You may want to research the term *virtual machine*, AKA *VM*.)

Comment: No I guess I would be right here. I don't want to boot another OS in a VM. The question is how can I achieve my desired behavior. It would probably mean to write a kernel module for Linux etc. so I don't expect a totally easy or premade solution!

Comment: No. This site is for programming related questions, and your question as written has absolutely nothing to do with programming. This site is for *specific questions about actual problems you're having with code or a programmers tool*. You're looking for [su] instead. If you're still not listening, read it yourself in the [help].

Comment: So why doesn't number 6. from the help center apply here? Or I can ask my question differently maybe then it becomes obvious as a programming question. I am doing p = malloc(512); fd = fopen("/dev/sda1", "rb"); fread(p, 512, 1, fd); jmp(p); but it fails executing the bootloader form the first partition. Any ideas what else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: #6 from the only numbered list in the [help/on-topic] is *Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools**.*  Not sure what you're asking here; none of that applies to your question except the *off-topic* portion. If you have changes to make to your question that would make it relevant here, you should [edit] the question to make them. (I'd think that at nearly 1300 rep you'd know that already.)

Comment: An operating system needs a different level of CPU access than a user program. That's why they invented VMs, and why you can't solve this problem without one. You aren't going to find an answer here on StackOverflow because there isn't one.

Comment: That's why I wrote that it must be a kernel module. E.g. similar to how kexec works but running bootcode instead of another kernel image.

Comment: So the goal is to wipe out Linux when you boot Windows, not having the two running side by side? OK, I guess that makes it barely on topic. I still don't think you're going to find an answer here.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/force-grub-to-boot-into-a-specific-kernel-os

Answer (score -1):

Starting a Windows system from a running Linux system, without a reboot and using live hardware (i.e. not in a VM) is simply impossible.

An operating system demands full control of the machine's hardware. Even if you managed to somehow "boot without reboot", from the point of view of the running Linux system, Windows would be a program attempting to illegally access ring-0 (administrative level) CPU instructions and would be simply killed.

Not possible. Your only option to run two full operating systems on the same physical hardware is through the use of virtual machines.

Comment: After careful consideration of the question, I now think they're asking how to run a program in ring 0 so that it has the required access. This would obviously kill the Linux host, but that appears to be the intent.

Comment: Would that even be possible? I mean, by the time the first OS finishes booting, the machine is no longer in real mode, the memory segmentation table is in place, interruptions are configured, etc. I think undoing all that to allow a Windows setup is,... well, rebooting, isn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly, it would be rebooting - except from a partition other than the default. I don't know if it's possible either.